# How to declare a specific time zone in a Scheduled Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

i write a functions that sync data every day using cloud functions.pubsub.schedule, and just to to know what is the time zone for Israer or i just wrote Israel?

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 6 * * *')
   .timeZone('Israel') 
  .onRun(async(context) => {
```

just want to know if it support tiime zone in israel like that

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please take a minute to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i just want to know what to write in timezone to get Israel time

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 11):

The time zone names used to schedule a Scheduled Cloud Function are the ones of the **tz database**. You will find a list of all possible values in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in the third column of the table.

So, for Israel it should be `Asia/Jerusalem`.

Comment: Its old, but was my first result on google, so worth to mention that default TZ is `America/Los_Angeles` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions